# Missing argument in bash getopts sets argument to next option

Tags: bash, getopts

I have a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

i_flag=false
v_flag=false

while getopts ":i:v:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    i  ) i_flag=true; echo $OPTARG;;
    v  ) v_flag=true; echo $OPTARG;;
    \? ) echo Unknown option: -$OPTARG >&2; exit 1;;
    :  ) echo "Missing option argument for -OPTARG" >&2; exit 1;;
  esac
done

echo $i_flag
echo $v_flag
```

When I run this without setting any options I get:

```
# ./opts_script.sh -i -v
-v
true
false
```

What I would expect to see is the output for both options indicating that no argument has been passed. However, the `-i` option is taking `-v` as its argument and setting the `i_flag` variable to `true`. It then leaves the `v_flag` variable as false because it isn't seeing it as an option.

I have also used `while getopts ":iv:" opts; do` so that the `-i` option does not take the next option as its argument. This, however, is undesired, because it allows the option to be unset; Not what I want.

My question, then, is thus: Is it possible to ensure that all provided options have arguments and that those arguments are not the next option if no argument is provided? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

It is problem, because the `getopt` accepts joined arguments too, e.g. for the following

```
getopts ":i:v:xyz"
```

will accept the

```
getopts -xyz
```

and the `$opt` will set  sequentally to `x` `y` and `z`. Also accepts the following too for the argument requiring a value - like your `-i`

```
script -iwww
```

e.g. not need the space - the `$OPTARG` would be set to `www`. Therefore, the following is accepted too

```
script -xyiwww
```

what sets, the `x`, `y` and the `i` with `$OPTARG` = `www`.

And because the above, the getopts could't differentiate between:

```
 script -iwww   #sets to the `$OPTARG` the string `www`
 #and
 script -iv     #set to the `$OPTARG` the string `v` altough the `-v` is an possible argument.
```

With some work is possible do some checks for the separated arguments, like

```
scrit -i -v
```

what will throws error if the `$OPTARG` (in this case `-v`) starts with `-` but this doesn't solve the above problems with the "joined" arguments...

Because my english isn't the best one, i hope the above make sense...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to let your input be *anything* "-v" is valid input. I suggest you do input validation, given that your input has some requirements. You could do some nasty/smart input validation checking whether the argument looks like an option flag, but often it's better to check that the input follows an expected pattern or that files given exist etc.